# custom chars wordlist generator

Tags: vb.net

I would like to generate a wordlist based on custom chars. right now what I have only display one. how can I make it display all unique combinations?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim num_letters As Integer = 5
    Dim num_words As Integer = 1
    Dim letters() As Char = "aeiouykzrsdjlxvn".ToCharArray()
    Dim rand As New Random()

    For i As Integer = 1 To num_words
        Dim word As String = ""
        For j As Integer = 1 To num_letters
            Dim letter_num As Integer = rand.Next(0,
                letters.Length - 1)
            word &= letters(letter_num)
        Next j

        Debug.Print(word)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: actual words or just combinations of characters?  are they all supposed to be 5 chars long?

Comment: I would like if possible like actual words like julie, vinzy etc.. and not nnnno, xeeee

Comment: how will the code know a real word from gibberish?

Comment: its fine, it could be like a made up name but readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created this function to switch between consonants and vowels, never repeat them ... Try it.

```
Function getName() As String
    Dim num_letters As Integer = 5
    Dim num_words As Integer = 1

    Dim vowel() As Char = "aeiou".ToCharArray()
    Dim consonants() As Char = "ykzrsdjlxvn".ToCharArray()

    Dim rand As New Random()

    Dim word As String = ""

    For i As Integer = 1 To num_words
        For j As Integer = 1 To num_letters
            If j Mod 2 = 0 Then
                'CONSONANTS
                Dim letter_num As Integer
                Do
                    letter_num = rand.Next(0, consonants.Length - 1)
                Loop Until (word.IndexOf(consonants(letter_num)) = -1)

                word &= consonants(letter_num)
            Else
                'VOWEL
                Dim letter_num As Integer
                Do
                    letter_num = rand.Next(0, vowel.Length - 1)
                Loop Until (word.IndexOf(vowel(letter_num)) = -1)

                word &= vowel(letter_num)
            End If

        Next j
    Next i
    Return word
End Function
```

Example of results: esira / edila / oyire / eradi / elijo / olexi / odeka / ovezi / etc...